В BIOS нет параметра "Виртуализация"
Скачал Docker Desktop, запускаю, выдаёт ошибку Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error
Пытался решить вопрос, смотрю а в биосе ни строчки про виртуализацию, проверял все кнопки по 3 раза. И я уверен что не работает именно из-за отсутствия виртуалки.


WSL - это Windows Subsystem for Linux. Проверьте, что у вас установлено WSL 2.

В этом компе параметр называется SVM.

Если хотите посмотреть видео с дрожащими руками съемок монитора на  телефон, то вот оно
https://youtu.be/Sy_0J11apKA?si=Bq3CBbzjhDgZhJaP&t=118
